# Sharing folders between more than two computer

Tags: shared-folders

I have 4 computer which ubbuntu 13.10 installed on all of them. I need to make a share folder between all to add and remove and change the contents  synchronously via the internet. So please tell me how can i do that. I am new in networking issues in ubuntu.
Bests

Comment: Are they all on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

I think NFS is the best and most easy way to make it, you can learn more about NFS and have a trial of it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html

Comment: and after sharing with NFS, you can write it to fstab to mount NFS at bootup. My office system works that way.

Comment: And when your NFS server is down? How does bootup work then?

Comment: @waltinator I mean the system can mount the NFS during the bootup. If NFS is down nothing will happen..it's just a folder has nothing to do with the basic filesystem.. So is my first comment ambiguous?